Projectivity under finite base change
Let $g:X'\to S'$ be a projective morphism between complex varieties. Let $\pi:S'\to S$ be a finite covering. Assume we have a proper morphism $f:X\to S$ such that we have the Cartesian diagram: $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X' @>>> X\\ @VgVV @VfVV\\ S' @>\pi>> S \end{CD}$$
Is it possible to show that the morphism $f:X\to S$ is also projective? I try to prove this by pushing down the relative ample line on $X'$ to $X$. And this has some problem that it may not be a line bundle again.
I known a related result which says that under the finite field extension $X_K$ is projective variety then the original variety $X$ (over field $k$) is also projective. (see for example here).

The sentence with "such that" ends with a diagram. Something is missing. You want it to be a pullback?

Oh thank you for pointing out, I forget to say it's a Cartesian diagram.
